# Not sure what this line of code does. (Embedded software for ARM)

Tags: c, embedded, arm

I recently came across this line of C-code in some embedded software, but I've never seen this syntax. I believe it has to do with storing something in non-initialized memory (but I could be totally wrong).

```
char *SomeName1 @ ".noinit";
```

there is also

```
#### #define DEF 100

char SomeName[DEF] @ ".noinit";
```

Anyone?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  The notation is non-standard.  You will need to look at the manual for the compiler that you are using, or that the software was intended to be compiled with.  It appears that the data should be uninitialized for some reason — presumably, the code will set the values before trying to read it.  But the detailed semantics can only be found in the relevant compiler manual.

Comment: What is the compiler name?

Answer (score 2):

If the code you have read was meant to be compiled with an IAR ARM compiler, then read the following excerpt from [the IAR C/C++ Development Guide](http://supp.iar.com/FilesPublic/UPDINFO/004916/arm/doc/EWARM_DevelopmentGuide.ENU.pdf)

> - The @ operator and the #pragma location directive for section
>     placement
>
> Use the @ operator or the #pragma location directive to
>   place groups of functions or global and static variables in named
>   sections, without having explicit control of each object. The sections
>   can, for example, be placed in specific areas of memory, or
>   initialized or copied in controlled ways using the section begin and
>   end operators. This is also useful if you want an interface between
>   separately linked units, for example an application project and a boot
>   loader project. Use named sections when absolute control over the
>   placement of individual variables is not needed, or not useful.

The pointer and the array will then both be placed in the no-init section of the memory. i.e. the startup code will not bother initialising these variables, hence the first time a program accesses them, they will (could potentially) contain garbage values.

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be variant of place-at / section/segment specification. Pragmas are usually used for that. The code probably means "Linker, place this in section .noinit... and the linker script places that in non-initialized memory section)

Answer (score 1):

It is a compiler specific extension (IAR EWARM compiler perhaps?) for locating a variable in a specific linker section.  It is not standard C - different compilers provide different means for doing similar things. It can also be used to locate at a specific address. No doubt your [compiler documentation](ftp://ftp.iar.se/WWWfiles/arm/webic/doc/EWARM_DevelopmentGuide.ENU.pdf) will elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

For sections without content (zero-initialized sections), the situation is reversed. The
linker arranges for zero initialization of all such sections at application startup, except
for those that have been mentioned in a *do not initialize* directive. Usually, only
`.noinit` sections are specified in a *do not initialize* directive, but you can add
any zero-initialized sections you like, and take direct control over when and how these
sections are initialized.

[image]